# Onclick change width of dropdown using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I've below code in which I'm trying to change `width` of dropdown upon click. I tried with `click` event but no success. Any help is appreciated.

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'testing1',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    .on('onClick', function() {
      document.getElementByTagName('select').style.width = '500';
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579748/how-to-achieve-autocomplete-feature-over-html-drop-down-or-select-element -->
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'testing1',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    .on('click', function() {
      document.getElementByTagName('select').style.width = '500';
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onClick` is not a valid handler in Jquery. Use `click` instead

Comment: Tried but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Select2 Events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events), no `click` event available.
Though you can use click on `.select2-container` like the following way:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'testing1',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    $('.select2-container').click(function() {
      $(this).css('width','500px');
      $('.select2-dropdown.select2-dropdown--below').attr('style', 'width: 500px !important');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select></select>
```

Though the preferred way is to use `open` event:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'testing1',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    .on('select2:open', function() {
      $('.select2-container').css('width','600px');
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select></select>
```

Comment: `click` handler worked fine. Used `focusout` handler to revert back to original size.

Comment: @Experimenter, that's really grate to know:)

Comment: is it possible to expand change width of box also after`click` event.

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287106/change-placeholder-on-link-click-in-html/57288300

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggleClass`, this is a handy jQuery event that allows you to toggle the class of, in this case the `select` By adding a id of something of your choice, for this example I will just use `box`, so:
`<select id="box">`

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#box.clicked {
    width: 200px;
}
```

This way you can use the following jQuery:

`.$('#box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});`

HTML:

`<select id="box"></select>`

This makes it so when you click on the select it adds the `#box.clicked` to the select and when you click on it again it changes to it's size set in `#box`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579748/how-to-achieve-autocomplete-feature-over-html-drop-down-or-select-element -->
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'testing1',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    .on('change', function() {
      $('.select2-container').css('width', '500px');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select></select>
</body>
</html>
```

The element in select 2 is ('.select2-container') and the event is on change.

Check if is what yuou are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(function() {
      $('select')
        .select2({
          placeholder: 'Search Command...',
          width: '200',
          multiple: false,
          data: [{
            id: '',
            text: ''
          }, {
            id: 'testing1',
            text: 'testing1'
          }, {
            id: 'testing 1,2,3',
            text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
          }],
          tokenSeparators: ['|']
        })
        .change(function() {
        $('.select2').css("width", "500px");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `select2:open` `select2:close` Event

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579748/how-to-achieve-autocomplete-feature-over-html-drop-down-or-select-element -->
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'testing1',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    .on('select2:open', function() {
       $('.select2-container').css('width','600px');
    })
   .on("select2:close", function () { 
 $('.select2-container').css('width','200px');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select></select>
</body>
</html>
```