# Change placeholder on link click in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

With below code I'm trying to change the `placeholder` for `select` element on link click. But no changes are seen as of now. Also I'm trying to figure out how to show `div` when click on gear icon. Currently it works when click on `div` but not for icon present in it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Dropdown - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579748/how-to-achieve-autocomplete-feature-over-html-drop-down-or-select-element -->
<!-- focus in-out event > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284729/onclick-change-width-of-dropdown-using-javascript/57284975#57284975 -->
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'rrrrrrr',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    $('.select2-container').click(function() {
      $(this).css('width','500px');
    });    
    $('.select2-container').focusout(function() {
      $(this).css('width','200px');
    });
    $('#changeCommand').click(function() {
      $('select').css('placeholder','Search Command...');
    });    
    $('#changePref').click(function() {
      $('select').css('placeholder','Search Preferences...');
    });
    $('#changeCD').click(function() {
      $('select').css('placeholder','Search Customer Default...');
    });    
});

</script>
<script>
<!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown -->
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select></select> <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()" style="border-radius: 3px;border: none;color: black; background-color: white;"><span>&#9881;</span></button></div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="changeCommand">Commands</a>
    <a id="changePref">Preferences</a>
    <a id="changeCD">Customer Default</a>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you replace and try .css by attr
https://api.jquery.com/attr/
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

Comment: just try like this `$('select').attr('placeholder','your text...');`

Comment: Thanks but not working.

Comment: `placeholder` is an HTML attribute, not a CSS property.

Comment: @Experimenter Do you want change only placeholders label? What about select2 data options? Do they remain always the same or do you have to re-initialize the plugin with other data?

Comment: Yes, only need to change placeholder options, not options.

Comment: Just figured out that when click link not any type of action taking place. Tried with alert. So something wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select')
    .select2({
      placeholder: 'Search Command...',
      allowClear: true,
      width: '200',
      multiple: false,
      data: [{
        id: '',
        text: ''
      }, {
        id: 'rrrrrrr',
        text: 'testing1'
      }, {
        id: 'testing 1,2,3',
        text: 'testing 1,2,3gffffff'
      }],
      tokenSeparators: ['|']
    })
    .on('select2:open', function() {
      $('.select2-container').css('width','600px');
    })
    .on("select2:close", function () { 
      $('.select2-container').css('width','200px');
    });
    $('#changeCommand').click(function() {
      $('.select2-selection__placeholder').text('Search Command...');
    });    
    $('#changePref').click(function() {
      $('.select2-selection__placeholder').text('Search Preferences...');
    });
    $('#changeCD').click(function() {
      $('.select2-selection__placeholder').text('Search Customer Default...');
    });    
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  if (event.target.classList.contains('dropbtn')) {  
    dropdowns.classList.toggle("show");    
  }
  else if (!event.target.classList.contains("dropbtn") && dropdowns.classList.contains("show")){
    dropdowns.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select></select> 
<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" style="border-radius: 3px;border: none;color: black; background-color: white;">&#9881;</button></div>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a id="changeCommand">Commands</a>
  <a id="changePref">Preferences</a>
  <a id="changeCD">Customer Default</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Experimenter, there are several issues in your code, the above solution is the closest I think:)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove remove the subscription on the window.onclick event.
The onclick event on you button will be fired when child elements are clicked. Your current logic will show and directly hide the dropdown

Comment: Yes but this will not collapse drop-down when click anywhere in blank space.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already I would bind an event to the document and check if an element with class drop-btn is clicked. If so, toggle the show class on the dropdown element, otherwise hide the dropdown element.

You can check it here : https://jsfiddle.net/70j5deat/4/